# How to download an online file directory (localhost) using Java

Tags: java, download, directory, localhost, fileserver

I have a static file server at "localhost:8888/fileserver".
I am trying to write a program in java to download the files from the server. The file server consists of three folders, therefore I am trying to write a script that automatically goes through the directory and copies it to my computer.

I know there is a wget function for linux that accomplishes this recursively. Is there a way to do this in Java?
Please could you advise on how I should go about doing this or proceed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code to go through an online directory and return back all the links needed to download.

After that I just need to download each individual link.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class WebCrawler {
    //Created a global list variable to save the links
    static List<String> createList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String url = "http://localhost:8888";
        System.out.println(myCrawler(url)+"\n"+"Size: "+myCrawler(url).size());

    }    

    public static List<String> myCrawler(String url) throws IOException{
        //Creates an open connection to a link
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

        //Recursively iterates through all the links provided on the initial url
        for (Element i : links) {
            String link = print("%s", i.attr("abs:href"));
            if (link.endsWith("/")){myCrawler(link);} //Recursive part, calls back on itself
            else {createList.add(link);}
        }
        return createList;  
    }

    //Translates the link into a readable string object
    private static String print(String msg, Object... args){return String.format(msg, args);}
}
```